# How to add &#xA; after text in XML element in Groovy MarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

Basically we are changing the datasource XML for an InDesign project the way the old. We don't want to change the InDesign so I have to adapt the new XML from the new datasource (a SOAP webservice via Mule ESB). I use groovy to convert said XML, all was going until I faced this issue. The old XML in InDesign only works with this special character added to after every text: `&#xA;`.

Here's an example of a working XML :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<w_import_saisie_web><w_evenement><w_titre>My Title&#xA;</w_titre></w_evenement>
</w_import_saisie_web>
```

I am unable to add the special character in the Groovy script : Here's what I tried so far :

```
root = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(payload)

    def xml = new StringWriter().with { w -> new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(w).with {
            mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")                       
                     "w_import_saisie_web"() {                      
                                "w_titre"( root.title + "&#xA;")    
                        }
                    }
        }
        w.toString()
    }
```

I also tried :

```
"w_titre"( root.title + '&#xA;') 
"w_titre"( root.title + '&amp'+'#xA;')  
"w_titre"( root.title + "&amp"+"#xA;")
```

etc

I can print this with no problem

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<w_import_saisie_web><w_evenement><w_titre>My Title</w_titre></w_evenement>
</w_import_saisie_web>
```

But I can't seem to do this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<w_import_saisie_web><w_evenement><w_titre>My Title&#xA;</w_titre></w_evenement>
</w_import_saisie_web>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What's `root` used for in your example? And I assumed from the first line that `payload` was a string, but then you seem to do `payload.title`?

Comment: Oops, I actually erased half my code because it wasn't relevant to my issue, but printing the XML and the title works well. The payload is a string coming from Mule yes. The issue is really adding the '"&#xA;" after the text. I edited my question.

Comment: So you're parsing the working XML example, and trying to add the escape into the title? Sorry, trying to work out from your question what are inputs and what are outputs

Comment: I have a huge soap response and I receive it as a string in this case it could just be <root><title>Yo</title></root>. What I want to do is convert this a new XML and add the line feed special characters to each elements. In this case <newxmlroot><newtitle>Yo&#xA;</newtitle></newxmlroot> . I hope that's clearer, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mkp.yieldUnescaped`:

```
println new StringWriter().with { w ->
    new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(w).with {
        escapeAttributes = false
        mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")                       
        w_import_saisie_web {                      
            w_titre {
                mkp.yieldUnescaped 'woo&#xA;'
            }
        }
    }
    w.toString()
}
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<w_import_saisie_web>
  <w_titre>woo&#xA;</w_titre>
</w_import_saisie_web>
```

And if you don't want to hardcode the `&#xA;`, you can use `escapeControlCharacters` from `XmlUtil`:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

println new StringWriter().with { w ->
    new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(w).with {
        escapeAttributes = false
        mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")                       
        w_import_saisie_web {                      
            w_titre {
                mkp.yieldUnescaped XmlUtil.escapeControlCharacters('woo\n')
            }
        }
    }
    w.toString()
}
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<w_import_saisie_web>
  <w_titre>woo&#10;</w_titre>
</w_import_saisie_web>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use xml cdata

```
<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>
```